# New JSdom API - errors

Tags: node.js, jsdom

node v8.10.0

Why does new JSdom API throw errors?

```
"*Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo*"
"*Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined]*"
"*Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null]*"
```

etc.

OLD API (works fine); [jsdom v11.3.0]

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");
var url = 'https://www.wp.pl';

var requestData = request(url, function(err, resp, HTMLdata) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log('Request success - we render jsdom page \n');
        jsdom.env({
            html: HTMLdata,
            features: {
                FetchExternalResources : ['script'],
                ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
                SkipExternalResources: false
            },
            done: function (err, window) {
                if (err) {console.log('ERR: ' + err);}
                var document = window.document;
                window.close();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

NEW API: [jsdom v15.1.1]

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

var url = 'https://www.wp.pl';
var requestData = request(url, function(err, resp, HTMLdata)
{
    if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200){
        console.log('Request success - we render jsdom page \n');
        var JSdom1 = new JSDOM(HTMLdata,
        {
            url : url,
            referrer : url,
            runScripts : 'dangerously',
            resources : 'usable'
        });
        if (JSdom1.onload){}
    }
});
```

for example because of new API:

```
"*%cWarning! background:red;color:white;font-weight:bold; WPJSlib is embedded incorrectly, probably 'src' is incorrectly extended. Contact ATFD for further information.*"
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

jsdom's new API automatically creates a [virtual console](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#virtual-consoles) for you that's piped to the real (node's) console. Previous versions of jsdom used to hide those errors.

You can simply provide an empty `VirtualConsole` instance in the options which will hide those errors again:

```
const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();
const dom = new JSDOM(``, { virtualConsole });
```